# Using UIPanGestureRecognizer in Xcode and velocity to determine swipe direction is too sensitive and switches rapidly between directions

Tags: ios, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

Clarification:

What I'm trying to achieve is this: the swiping gestures (up, down, right and left) are on a WebView. When any of the gestures occur this is what it needs to happen: as soon as the swipe begins, an action must begin (the action is actually loading a html link which moves an ip camera to either up,down,right,left). The html link makes the camera to go all the way to the right or left or up or down. I have another html link which when loaded will tell the ip camera to stop.

So what it needs to happen is when the state is UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan the link load and moves the camera continuously until the user isn't touching the screen and the state becomes UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded and triggers the other html link to run in WebView which link will stop the camera from moving. As we speak my initial code posted does that but the swiping was too sensitive. This problem is fixed with your code but now the second link loads instantly after the first one, not allowing the camera to move. Does it make sense?? First link needs to run until the finger is lifted.

---

Original question:

I was trying to determine the swipe direction using velocity in a UIPanGestureRecognizer, which I managed and it detects the right, left, up and down swipes, it triggers the appropriate actions based on the swipe direction and again the correct actions when UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded for each swipe, BUT, my problem in the code below is that the direction is very sensitive for example during a swipe to the right it recognises most part of the swipe as to the right but also some swipe up or down in between. As the swipe is not always perfectly in a straight line, what I would like to find is to only trigger the action for swipe right if the swipe is MOSTLY to the right and ignore the tiny pixel deviations.

Also, ideally for my project is to trigger the action on a given swipe direction only once just like in the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, but using it I have a problem with UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded as it doesn't let the swipe action run until I lift my finger off the screen, it finishes the swipe action right away even though my finger is still swiping.

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

in ViewDidLoad I have:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
[_myWebView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
[gestureRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[gestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
```

and in my class I have:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:_myWebView];

if(velocity.x > 0)//right
{
   //my action here

  if ( [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
  { //my action when swipe finished here }
}
else if(velocity.x < 0)//left
{
   //my action here

  if ( [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
  { //my action when swipe finished here }
}
else if(velocity.y > 0)//down
{
   //my action here

  if ( [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
  { //my action when swipe finished here }
}
else if(velocity.y < 0)//up
{
   //my action here

  if ( [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
  { //my action when swipe finished here }
}
```

Thank you, any clarifications please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have some "horizontal" direction detection if the `x` component was some reasonable multiple of the `y` component. So, perhaps if `x` was five times `y`, that could be considered horizontal swipe. And vice versa for vertical. Whether five is the right multiple is up to you (using tan<sup>-1</sup>, you can see that translates to roughly 11.3° from absolute horizontal/vertical), but it's conceptually one way to tackle it easily.

For example, here's a gesture recognizer that will send a camera a command to initiate movement in a particular direction when the user starts a swipe in that direction, and will tell the camera to stop when the user lifts their finger off the screen:

```
CGFloat const gestureMinimumTranslation = 20.0;

typedef enum : NSInteger {
    kCameraMoveDirectionNone,
    kCameraMoveDirectionUp,
    kCameraMoveDirectionDown,
    kCameraMoveDirectionRight,
    kCameraMoveDirectionLeft
} CameraMoveDirection;

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CameraMoveDirection direction;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    [self.viewWithGestureRecognizer addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

// This is my gesture recognizer handler, which detects movement in a particular
// direction, conceptually tells a camera to start moving in that direction
// and when the user lifts their finger off the screen, tells the camera to stop.

- (void)handleSwipe:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        direction = kCameraMoveDirectionNone;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged && direction == kCameraMoveDirectionNone)
    {
        direction = [self determineCameraDirectionIfNeeded:translation];

        // ok, now initiate movement in the direction indicated by the user's gesture

        switch (direction) {
            case kCameraMoveDirectionDown:
                NSLog(@"Start moving down");
                break;

            case kCameraMoveDirectionUp:
                NSLog(@"Start moving up");
                break;

            case kCameraMoveDirectionRight:
                NSLog(@"Start moving right");
                break;

            case kCameraMoveDirectionLeft:
                NSLog(@"Start moving left");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // now tell the camera to stop
        NSLog(@"Stop");
    }
}

// This method will determine whether the direction of the user's swipe

- (CameraMoveDirection)determineCameraDirectionIfNeeded:(CGPoint)translation
{
    if (direction != kCameraMoveDirectionNone)
        return direction;

    // determine if horizontal swipe only if you meet some minimum velocity

    if (fabs(translation.x) > gestureMinimumTranslation)
    {
        BOOL gestureHorizontal = NO;

        if (translation.y == 0.0)
            gestureHorizontal = YES;
        else
            gestureHorizontal = (fabs(translation.x / translation.y) > 5.0);

        if (gestureHorizontal)
        {
            if (translation.x > 0.0)
                return kCameraMoveDirectionRight;
            else
                return kCameraMoveDirectionLeft;
        }
    }
    // determine if vertical swipe only if you meet some minimum velocity

    else if (fabs(translation.y) > gestureMinimumTranslation)
    {
        BOOL gestureVertical = NO;

        if (translation.x == 0.0)
            gestureVertical = YES;
        else
            gestureVertical = (fabs(translation.y / translation.x) > 5.0);

        if (gestureVertical)
        {
            if (translation.y > 0.0)
                return kCameraMoveDirectionDown;
            else
                return kCameraMoveDirectionUp;
        }
    }

    return direction;
}

@end
```

This demonstrates how you could determine the initial direction of a pan gesture and then act once the initial direction is established, as well as upon the end of the gesture.

Comment: OK, this solution identifies correctly the right, left, up and down but my other problem is still there. The action starts as soon as it identifies a valid swipe and finishes instantly even if my finger is still swiping, triggering my other action. What I'm after is for my first action to start as soon as I start swiping and to only finish running when my finger is off, when it triggers my second action to start.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Rob, for my swiping issue, now the swipe direction is identified correctly and only triggers the action once and not 15 times. My big problem with the above code is that now it doesn't identify then my finger is off the screen so the  UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded gets called only when the swiping finishes by lifting the finger off the screen, so then my second action starts. Hope I'm clear enough, if not, I'll try to give more info.

Comment: thanks for editing it for me. I was about to but I noticed you did it. So thanks

Comment: The user controls just the direction of the movement (up,down,right,left). The action has to continue until the finger is lifted otherwise there will be too many swipes to move the camera 280 degrees.

Comment: Conclusion: Swipe right - a html link loads and runs(the camera starts rotating) - lift the finger - load another html link which stops the camera rotation

Comment: thanks I'm trying it right now, I'll post here soon. Sorry for all the hassle. I admit I just wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Rob you thought me a few lessons today. Not just by fixing and pretty much retyping my code but I also learned to explain myself a bit better when asking for help.I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP ROB AND YES THE CODE IS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS AFTER AND WORKS PERFECTLY !!! THANK YOU SIR !

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you can use translation instead of velocity of the gesture - that'll give you the distance traveled from the beginning to the end of the swipe and not the direction of the movement at the very end of the swipe as with velocity.

Secondly, you probably should check if the gesture state is 'Ended' before checking the direction. Now you repeat the same check in each 'if'.

To get the direction you can either get the angle of the translation using atan2 trigonometric function with x and y of the translation or if it's OK to always interpret the gesture as a swipe in one of 4 directions, simply find whether x or y has larger absolute value and then if it's positive or negative.

Comment: OP probably doesn't want to check for end of gesture otherwise it would be better to use swipe gestures; this is the curious problem that the OP is trying to solve. Personally, I think he should use a standard `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` as OP's desired gesture is very non-standard (typically the user should always have the ability to effectively cancel a gesture once started, and OP's solution doesn't provide that). But to each his own.

Comment: You're right, but from what I get he would like to recognize direction both during and at the end of the gesture. This makes my second point kind of invalid, and as to using translation I'm not sure if he would like to measure the direction of the movement from the beginning or at any given moment. When it comes to measuring the direction your answer is indeed perfectly allright. I could only add that in order to reduce the 'randomness' of the direction he could keep an array of last few gesture positions as a history and compare last one with one n-th one before.

Comment: Agreed. I updated my answer to have the gesture recognizer cancel itself as soon as it successfully identifies a gesture to make sure you don't have any extraneous recognitions taking place as, for example, the user lifts their finger off the screen.